# flink job failed when encountered DB Connection Exception

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm newer to flink. My flink job recieved messages from mq, and do some rule check and summary calculation, then write the result to rdbms. Sometimes the job will encounter NullPointException(due to my silly code) , or MQ connection Exception(due to non-exist Topic),and it just halted current message-processing, the job is still running, then next messages will still trigger the exception.

But today I restart DB and the job failed. What's the difference?

Comment: forget the above MQ connection Exception(due to non-exist Topic) , the exception happens when submit a job.

Comment: Another Exception for job-not-failed : dulicate keys confilicts.